# CRUD for Codeigniter, grocerycrud or carbogrid?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

I am using CodeIgniter for my website. I am currently trying to implement an admin section where I've to enable CRUD features.

I searched online and came across two different extensions for CI.

1. Grocerycrud http://www.grocerycrud.com
2. Carbogrid http://carbogrid.com

Can anyone suggest which one is better ?

Edit: I am using PostgreSQL database.

Comment: I am doing basic 'insert' 'delete' 'update' 'create' options in CI itself. But when doing the process for a big list,an admin UI, I thought a stable built-in interface  will be better.

Comment: The database I am using is postgresql

Comment: grocery crud is easier. But it only support mySQL

Comment: I agree grocery crud looks easier and a smoother design. I am just getting started on both and have dropped interest in carbogrid though it is one to take note of if he ever involves more modern javascript.